# Application of the divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $C^1$ boundary.  I want to prove that $$\int_{\partial \Omega} \nu(y) \cdot \frac{y}{|y|^3} \, dS(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0 \in \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \overline{\Omega} \\ 4\pi & 0 \in \Omega \end{array}\right.$$ where $\nu(y)$ is the unit exterior normal, and $dS$ is surface measure on $\partial\Omega$.  If $0 \in \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\overline{\Omega}$ we'll use the divergence theorem applied to the $C^1$ vector field $F(y)=y/|y|^3$.  In the case $0 \in \Omega$, we'll do the same thing to the vector field $y/|y|^3 \in C^1(\Omega\setminus\overline{B(0,\varepsilon)})$ for $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small.  In either case, the result should follow from $\operatorname{div} F=0$, but I am unable to show this.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that $y/|y|^3=\nabla (|y|^{-1})$ so that your integrand is $\partial_\nu f$, with $f(y)=1/|y|$.

If $0\in \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \bar{\Omega}$, then $f$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ so that the divergence theorem gives
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} \partial_\nu f(y) dS = \int_\Omega \Delta f =0.
$$
If $0\in \Omega$ and $\Omega_\varepsilon=\Omega\setminus B(0,\varepsilon)$, then $f$ is harmonic in $\Omega_\varepsilon$ so that by the divergence theorem
$$
0= \int_\Omega \Delta f = \int_{\partial \Omega_\varepsilon} \partial_\nu f(y) dS
$$
The last integral is equal to
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} \partial_\nu f(y) dS - \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \partial_\nu f(y) dy.
$$
Now the integral over the boundary of the ball we can compute since $\nu(y)=y/\varepsilon$ and we get
$$
\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \partial_\nu f(y) dy= \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}= \frac{4\pi \varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon^2}=4\pi.
$$
Combining all this, we get the result.

Comment: I was able to come up with roughly this solution assuming that $\operatorname{div} F=0$.  But why is $\operatorname{div} F=0$?  Sorry if this is trivial; analysis is not my area.

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd: Could you be more specific? Do you know the definition of $\text{div}F$? Do you know how to take partial derivatives?

Comment: I do.  And you can disregard; I figured out I was making a silly mistake.